# c++ std::array implementation

Tags: c++, array, collections, template-meta-programming

Just after a review of my implementation of std::array. I created this to find the sweet spot between speed and nice code. I would really appreciate any guidance towards improving.

Note: I use parts of my meta-programming library you can find: https://github.com/sigma-blight/sigma_api [sigma_api/sigma/meta/].

```
/*  Static Size Container Array
*
* Wrapper class to a c-array of Tp_[n_]
*
* @tparam Tp_   -> element type
* @tparam n_    -> size of array
*/
template<typename Tp_, Size n_>
class Array
{
    /*  EnableCMem
    * check for the ability to 
    *   use `memcpy` and `memmove`
    *   from a type Vp_ to a type Tp_
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    using EnableCMem = meta::BoolConstant<
        sizeof(Vp_) == sizeof(Tp_) &&
        std::is_pod<Tp_>::value &&
        std::is_pod<Vp_>::value
    >;

    /*  Store size of data array in type
    *       for zero overhead
    */
    using DataSize = meta::SizeConstant<sizeof(Tp_) * n_>;

    /*  Raw Data
    */
    Tp_ _data[n_];

public:

    //============================================
    //          ** Initialisation **
    //============================================

    /*  Maintain default initialisation
    *       from compilier
    *
    * default:
    *   ~ Default Ctor
    *   ~ Copy Ctor
    *   ~ Move Ctor
    *   ~ Destructor
    *   ~ Copy Assignment Operator
    *   ~ Move Assignment Operator
    */

    Array(void)             = default;
    Array(const Array &)    = default;
    Array(Array &&)         = default;
    ~Array(void)            = default;

    Array & operator = (const Array &)  = default;
    Array & operator = (Array &&)       = default;

    /*  Values Constructor
    *
    * move a variadic list of values into the raw data
    *
    * enabled when exactly n_ many values are provided
    *
    * @tparam Tps_    -> parameter pack of arguments to move assign
    *
    * ASSERT: Every Tps_ is move assignable
    */
    template<typename ... Tps_,
        typename = meta::EnableIf_t<
            meta::VariadicSize_v<Tps_ ... > == n_
        >>
    Array(Tps_ && ... values)
        : _data{ std::move(values) ... }
    {}


    //============================================
    //             ** Data Access **
    //============================================

    /*  Subcript Operator
    *
    * access an individual element in the array
    *
    * @param index  -> element in the array
    */
    Tp_ & operator[] (const Size & index) { return Array::_data[index]; }
    const Tp_ & operator[] (const Size & index) const { return Array::_data[index]; }

    /*  Iterators
    *
    * access [begin, end) pointers of the array
    */
    Tp_ * begin(void) { return Array::_data; }
    Tp_ * end(void) { return Array::_data + n_; }

    const Tp_ * begin(void) const { return Array::_data; }
    const Tp_ * end(void) const { return Array::_data + n_; }

    /*  First and Last
    *
    * access the first and last element in array
    */
    Tp_ & front(void) { return *Array::_data; }
    Tp_ & back(void) { return *(Array::_data + n_ - 1); }

    const Tp_ & front(void) const { return *Array::_data; }
    const Tp_ & back(void) const { return *(Array::_data + n_ - 1); }

    /*  Raw Data
    *
    * access a pointer to the raw data
    */
    Tp_ * data(void) { return Array::_data; }
    const Tp_ * data(void) const { return Array::_data; }


    //============================================
    //             ** Utilities **
    //============================================

    /*  Array size
    *
    * static size of array -> n_
    */
    static constexpr Size size(void) { return n_; }

    /*  Array Fill
    *
    * copy value to every element in array
    *
    * @param value  -> value to copy assign
    *
    * ASSERT: copy assignable from const Vp_ to Tp_
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    void fill(const Vp_ & value)
    {
        static_assert(meta::CopyAssignable_v<Tp_, const Vp_>,
        "Array<Tp_, n_>::fill(const Vp_ &) ~ Invalid Vp_, requires copy assignability from const Vp_ to Tp_ \n");

        std::fill(Array::begin(), Array::end(), value);
    }


    /*  Array Copy
    * 
    * copy data from rhs array to lhs
    *
    * enable if c-styled copy available between types
    *
    * @param array  -> the rhs Array of any type
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    meta::EnableIf_t<EnableCMem<const Vp_>::value>
    copy(const Array<Vp_, n_> & array)
    {
        memcpy(Array::_data, array.begin(), DataSize::value);
    }

    /*  Array Copy
    *
    * iterate copy from rhs array to lhs
    *
    * enable if c-styled copy is NOT available between types
    *
    * @param array  -> the rhs Array of any type
    *
    * ASSERT: copy assignable from const Vp_ to Tp_
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    meta::EnableIf_t<!EnableCMem<const Vp_>::value>
    copy(const Array<Vp_, n_> & array)
    {
        static_assert(meta::CopyAssignable_v<Tp_, const Vp_>,
        "Array<Tp_, n_>::copy(const Array<Vp_, n_> &) ~ Invalid Vp_, requires copy assignability from const Vp_ to Tp_ \n");

        std::copy(array.begin(), array.end(), Array::begin());
    }

    /*  Array Move
    *
    * move data from rhs array to lhs
    *
    * enable if c-styled move available between types
    *
    * @param array  -> rhs Array of any type
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    meta::EnableIf_t<EnableCMem<Vp_>::value>
    move(Array<Vp_, n_> && array)
    {
        memmove(Array::_data, array.begin(), DataSize::value);
    }

    /*  Array Move
    *
    * iterate move from rhs array to lhs
    *
    * enable if c-styled move NOT available between types
    *
    * @param array  -> rhs Array of any type
    *
    * ASSERT: move assignable from Vp_ to Tp_
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    meta::EnableIf_t<!EnableCMem<Vp_>::value>
    move(Array<Vp_, n_> && array)
    {
        static_assert(meta::MoveAssignable_v<Tp_, Vp_>,
        "Array<Tp_, n_>::move(Array<Vp_, n_> &&) ~ Invalid Vp_, requires move assignability from Vp_ to Tp_ \n");

        std::move(array.begin(), array.end(), Array::begin());
    }

    /*  Array Swap
    *
    * swap data betwen rhs array and lhs array
    *
    * @param array  -> rhs Array to swap
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    void swap(Array<Vp_, n_> & array)
    {
        auto array_temp = std::move(array);
        array = std::move(*this);
        *this = std::move(array_temp);
    }

    //============================================
    //             ** Operators **
    //============================================

    /*  Function Operator
    *
    * call `function` for every element
    *
    * @param function   -> function to call
    *
    * ASSERT: function is callable as 
    *           function(Tp_ &, const Size &)
    */
    void operator() (auto function)
    {
        static_assert(meta::Callable_v<decltype(function), Tp_ &, const Size &>,
        "Array<Tp_, n_>::operator()(auto function) ~ Invalid function, requires signature function(Tp_ &, const Size &) \n");

        for (Size i = 0; i != n_; ++i)
            function(Array::_data[i], i);
    }

    /*  Array Cast
    *
    * creates an implicit conversion from 
    * this Array<Tp_> to an Array<Vp_>
    *
    * copies data from this to lhs
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    operator Array<Vp_, n_> (void)
    {
        Array<Vp_, n_> conversion;
        conversion.copy(*this);
        return conversion;
    }

    /*  Equality
    *
    * validate if every element in rhs array is
    * equal to every element in lhs array
    *
    * @param array  -> rhs Array of any type
    *
    * ASSERT: equatability between Tp_ and const Vp_
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    auto operator == (const Array<Vp_, n_> & array)
    {
        static_assert(meta::Equatable_v<Tp_, const Vp_>,
        "Array<Tp_, n_>::operator==(const Array<Vp_, n_> &) ~ Invalid Vp_, requires equatability between Tp_ and const Vp_ \n");

        return std::equal(array.begin(), array.end(), Array::begin());
    }

    /*  Scalar Equality
    *
    * validate if value is equal to
    * every element in lhs array
    *
    * @param value  -> value of any type
    *
    * ASSERT: equatability between Tp_ and const Vp_
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    auto operator == (const Vp_ & value)
    {
        static_assert(meta::Equatable_v<Tp_, const Vp_>,
        "Array<Tp_, n_>::operator==(const Vp_ &) ~ Invalid Vp_, requires equatability between Tp_ and const Vp_ \n");

        return std::equal(Array::begin(), Array::end(), value);
    }

    /*  Inequality
    *
    * return the inverse of equality
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    auto operator != (const Array<Vp_, n_> & array)
    {
        return !(*this == array);
    }

    /*  Scalar Inequality
    *
    * return the inverse of scalar inequality
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    auto operator != (const Vp_ & value)
    {
        return !(*this == value);
    }


    /*  Addition
    *
    * assign the addition of every element
    * in rhs array and every element in lhs
    * array to a new instance and return
    *
    * @param array  -> rhs Array of any type
    *
    * ASSERT: addability between Tp_ and const Vp_
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    auto operator + (const Array<Vp_, n_> & array)
    {
        static_assert(meta::Addable_v<Tp_, const Vp_>,
        "Array<Tp_, n_>::operator+(const Array<Vp_, n_> &) ~ Invalid Vp_, requires addability between Tp_ and const Vp_ \n");

        Array<meta::AddableTest<Tp_, const Vp_>, n_> result;
        result([&, this](auto & elem, const auto & index)
        {
            elem = this->_data[index] + array[index];
        });
        return result;
    }

    /*  Scalar Addition
    *
    * assign the addition of rhs value and 
    * every element in lhs array to 
    * a new instance and return
    *
    * @param value  -> rhs value of any type
    *
    * ASSERT: addability between Tp_ and const Vp_
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    auto operator + (const Vp_ & value)
    {
        static_assert(meta::Addable_v<Tp_, const Vp_>,
        "Array<Tp_, n_>::operator+(const Vp_ &) ~ Invalid Vp_, requires addability between Tp_ and const Vp_ \n");

        Array<meta::AddableTest<Tp_, const Vp_>, n_> result;
        result([&, this](auto & elem, const auto & index)
        {
            elem = this->_data[index] + value;
        });
        return result;
    }

    /*  Negation
    *
    * assign the negation of every element
    * in rhs array to new instance and return
    *
    * ASSERT: negatability of a const Tp_
    */
    auto operator - (void)
    {
        static_assert(meta::Negatable_v<Tp_>,
        "Array<Tp_, n_>::operator-(void) ~ Invalid Tp_, requires negatability on a Tp_ \n");

        Array<meta::NegatableTest<Tp_>, n_> result;
        result([&, this](auto & elem, const auto & index)
        {
            elem = -(this->_data[index]);
        });
        return result;
    }

    /*  Subtraction
    *
    * assign the subtraction of every element
    * in rhs array and every element in the lhs
    * array to a new instance and return
    *
    * @param array  -> rhs Array of any type
    *
    * ASSERT: subtractability between Tp_ and const Vp_
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    auto operator - (const Array<Vp_, n_> & array)
    {
        static_assert(meta::Subtractable_v<Tp_, const Vp_>,
        "Array<Tp_, n_>::operator-(const Array<Vp_, n_> &) ~ Invalid Vp_, requires subtractability between Tp_ and const Vp_ \n");

        Array<meta::SubtractableTest<Tp_, const Vp_>, n_> result;
        result([&, this](auto & elem, const auto & index)
        {
            elem = this->_data[index] - array[index];
        });
        return result;
    }

    /*  Scalar Subtraction
    *
    * assign the subtraction of rhs value and 
    * every element in lhs array to 
    * a new instance and return
    *
    * @param value  -> rhs value of any type
    *
    * ASSERT: subtractability between Tp_ and const Vp_
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    auto operator - (const Vp_ & value)
    {
        static_assert(meta::Subtractable_v<Tp_, const Vp_>,
        "Array<Tp_, n_>::operator-(const Vp_ &) ~ Invalid Vp_, requires subtractability between Tp_ and const Vp_ \n");

        Array<meta::SubtractableTest<Tp_, const Vp_>, n_> result;
        result([&, this](auto & elem, const auto & index)
        {
            elem = this->_data[index] - value;
        });
        return result;
    }

    /*  Product
    *
    * assign the product of every element
    * in rhs array and every element in the lhs
    * array to a new instance and return
    *
    * @param array  -> rhs Array of any type
    *
    * ASSERT: multiplicativity between Tp_ and const Vp_
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    auto operator * (const Array<Vp_, n_> & array)
    {
        static_assert(meta::Multiplicative_v<Tp_, const Vp_>,
        "Array<Tp_, n_>::operator*(const Array<Vp_, n_> &) ~ Invalid Vp_, requires multiplicativity between Tp_ and const Vp_ \n");

        Array<meta::MultiplicativeTest<Tp_, const Vp_>, n_> result;
        result([&, this](auto & elem, const auto & index)
        {
            elem = this->_data[index] * array[index];
        });
        return result;
    }

    /*  Scalar Product
    *
    * assign the product of rhs value and 
    * every element in lhs array to 
    * a new instance and return
    *
    * @param value  -> rhs value of any type
    *
    * ASSERT: multiplicativity between Tp_ and const Vp_
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    auto operator * (const Vp_ & value)
    {
        static_assert(meta::Multiplicative_v<Tp_, const Vp_>,
        "Array<Tp_, n_>::operator*(const Vp_ &) ~ Invalid Vp_, requires multiplicativity between Tp_ and const Vp_ \n");

        Array<meta::MultiplicativeTest<Tp_, const Vp_>, n_> result;
        result([&, this](auto & elem, const auto & index)
        {
            elem = this->_data[index] * value;
        });
        return result;
    }

    /*  Quotient
    *
    * assign the quotient of every element
    * in rhs array and every element in the lhs
    * array to a new instance and return
    *
    * @param array  -> rhs Array of any type
    *
    * ASSERT: divisibility between Tp_ and const Vp_
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    auto operator / (const Array<Vp_, n_> & array)
    {
        static_assert(meta::Divisible_v<Tp_, const Vp_>,
        "Array<Tp_, n_>::operator/(const Array<Vp_, n_> &) ~ Invalid Vp_, requires divisbility between Tp_ and const Vp_ \n");

        Array<meta::DivisibleTest<Tp_, const Vp_>, n_> result;
        result([&, this](auto & elem, const auto & index)
        {
            elem = this->_data[index] / array[index];
        });
        return result;
    }

    /*  Scalar Quotient
    *
    * assign the quotient of rhs value and 
    * every element in lhs array to 
    * a new instance and return
    *
    * @param value  -> rhs value of any type
    *
    * ASSERT: divisibility between Tp_ and const Vp_
    */
    template<typename Vp_>
    auto operator / (const Vp_ & value)
    {
        static_assert(meta::Divisible_v<Tp_, const Vp_>,
        "Array<Tp_, n_>::operator/(const Vp_ &) ~ Invalid Vp_, requires divisbility between Tp_ and const Vp_ \n");

        Array<meta::DivisibleTest<Tp_, const Vp_>, n_> result;
        result([&, this](auto & elem, const auto & index)
        {
            elem = this->_data[index] / value;
        });
        return result;
    }

};
```

Answer (score 5):

You did not provide the implementation of your constructors or assignment operators so its hard to tell if they are good or not.

Also nice to add easier access to const iterators:

```
const Tp_ * cbegin(void) const { return Array::_data; }
const Tp_ * cend(void)   const { return Array::_data + n_; }
   //       ^ add the c
```

Otherwise you need to cast the object to const to get accesses to the const version of `begin()` and `end()`.

I don't see the need for this:

```
template<typename Vp_>
meta::EnableIf_t<EnableCMem<const Vp_>::value>
copy(const Array<Vp_, n_> & array)
{
    memcpy(Array::_data, array.begin(), DataSize::value);
}
```

Yes I see what you are doing. But you other version already does this under the covers.

```
template<typename Vp_>
meta::EnableIf_t<!EnableCMem<const Vp_>::value>
copy(const Array<Vp_, n_> & array)
{
    static_assert(meta::CopyAssignable_v<Tp_, const Vp_>,
    "Array<Tp_, n_>::copy(const Array<Vp_, n_> &) ~ Invalid Vp_, requires copy assignability from const Vp_ to Tp_ \n");

    std::copy(array.begin(), array.end(), Array::begin());
}
```

Because `std::copy()` already has the best version built in. There is no need to optimize something that is already optimized. If it is not optimized by your standard library, then they have already measured it and determined it is not worth the effort.

Same comment applied to the `move()`.

Using the assignment operators to implement swap. Interesting.

Ok it looks like it could work but this is probably not the most efficient way to swap two arrays.

```
template<typename Vp_>
void swap(Array<Vp_, n_> & array)
{
    auto array_temp = std::move(array);
    array = std::move(*this);
    *this = std::move(array_temp);
}
```

First you make a copy (using move construction). Which means moving all the elements out of `array` into `array_temp`. Next you move assign. This means moving all the elements from `*this` into `array`. Then your last step is to move all the elements from temp array into `*this.

So you are basically doing three sets of moves, where each move is probably implemented as a swap operation. It would be easier to just run through the arrays and swap the elements in the arrays.

```
template<typename Vp_>
void swap(Array<Vp_, n_> & array)
{
    for(Size i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(this->operator[](i), array[i]);
    }
}
```

The operators section. I see no need for any of these. That is why we have algorithms.

Comment: Thankyou for your feedback!
***
Couple of follow ups:
***
the constructors and assignments are all created by default to let the compiler optimise them as best as possible. I found this to be faster than implementing them myself.
***
what are the advantage to the cbegin and cend when there are const overloads?
***
the reason for the c-styled copy/move, was purely found from benchmark improvements. I found about a 50% increase especially with larger sized arrays with memcpy vs std::copy (and the respective moves)
***
I'll have a look at std::swap, I didn't consider that thankyou!

Comment: @FletcherBlight: To get a const iterator from a non cost object now you need to do: `const_cast<Array<int,5> const&>(myArray).begin()` or `Array<int,5> const& myArrayRef = myArray; myArrayRef.begin();` Both seem long winded compared to `myArray.cbegin();`

Comment: @FletcherBlight: I find it interesting that `memcpy ` is faster than `std::copy` especially since on my system `std::copy` is specialized to use `memcpy` for POD. Which suggests to me that you have got something wrong (Sorry but I trust the standard library more than hand written code).

Comment: @FletcherBlight: I am surprised the default implementations of the move semantics work. But I am sure you have tested it. Did it actually move the content (or was it copied)?

Comment: I'll add the cbegin in, I do see your point. But you could write: const auto it = myArray.begin();

Comment: I'll upload some benchmarks so you can see the difference, it surprised me too though I've always thought std::copy was faster than memcpy.

Comment: `const auto it = myArray.begin();` That's not quite the same object. Put print statements into your `begin()` see which one gets called. Since the `const` here is on the iterator it does not stop you modifying the container it points at.